# Why are pulses not generated?

Tags: arduino, schematics, interrupts

> Task: Implement interrupt processing when the button is pressed, and the very start on the rising edge, the interrupt pin and to which the button is connected 11. Implement the processing of the button press through interrupts using the library function `PinChangeInt`. To generate pulses, use the configured timer Timer 0, register for comparison A. Also, the pulse frequency is 1290 Hz, the PWM fill factor is 81%, the PWM generation method is Normal PWM, the number of pulses is 5500.

Why doesn't my program generate pulses?

```c
    #include <PinChangeInt.h>
    
    const int interruptPin = 11;
    const int pulsePin = 6;
    volatile bool buttonPressed = false;
    volatile int pulseCount = 0;
    
    void setup() {
      // Set interrupt pin as input
      pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
      Serial.begin(9600);
    
      // Configure PinChangeInt to trigger on rising edge of interrupt pin
        PCintPort::attachInterrupt(interruptPin, handleInterrupt, RISING);
    
      // Configure Timer 0 to generate pulses
      TCCR0A = 0b10000011; // Normal PWM mode, non-inverted output
      TCCR0B = 0b00000011; // Clock prescaler = 64
      OCR0A = 122; // Compare register value for 1290 Hz frequency and 81% duty cycle
    
      // Set pulse pin as output
      pinMode(pulsePin, OUTPUT);
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // Check if button was pressed
      Serial.println("LOOP");
      if (buttonPressed) {
        // Reset buttonPressed flag
        buttonPressed = false;
    
        // Generate pulses
        pulseCount = 0;
        TCNT0 = 0; // Reset timer counter
        TIMSK0 |= (1 << OCIE0A); // Enable timer interrupt on compare A
        while (pulseCount < 5500) {
          // Output pulse on pulse pin
          digitalWrite(pulsePin, HIGH);
          delayMicroseconds(311); // Pulse width for 81% duty cycle
          digitalWrite(pulsePin, LOW);
          delayMicroseconds(719); // Pulse period - pulse width
        }
        TIMSK0 &= ~(1 << OCIE0A); // Disable timer interrupt on compare A
      }
    }
    
    void handleInterrupt() {
      // Set buttonPressed flag
      Serial.println("HANDLE");
      buttonPressed = true;
    }
    
    ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {
      // Increment pulseCount
      pulseCount++;
    }
```

Schema: [image]

Comment: This should be asked in the Arduino Stack Exchange, and deleted here.

Comment: Additionally, we need actual schematics here and not "pictures of wires and connectors". Don't force the reader to dig up the actual schematics of whatever board you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of problems is your interrupt handler:

```c
void handleInterrupt() {
  // Set buttonPressed flag
  Serial.println("HANDLE");
  buttonPressed = true;
}
```

It is usually a bad idea to use the serial functions from inside an interrupt.  The serial functions use interrupts.  Interrupts are disabled while your interrupt handler is executing.  Most likely, your program is sitting at `Serial.println("HANDLE");` and unable to do anything.

Comment out the `Serial.println("HANDLE");` line and see if it works.

Comment: nothing changed, also, for some reason `Serial.println("LOOP")` doesn't print once

Comment: Have you built it for real, or are you using a simulator?

Comment: I use a simulator Proteus

Comment: So, back up and start over.  Can you turn on a GPIO pin in the simulator?  Write a simple program that does nothing but switch the GPIO output.  Remove all the button and interrupt stuff.  Just a couple of `digitalWrite`s in the `loop()` function with a delay.  Does that make a signal?

Comment: if just leave this circuit and just do `digitalWrite` in the `loop`, the signal is generated

Comment: there are some problems in the `setup` method, when I comment out other parts leaving `setup` it just hangs

Comment: OP has posted duplicate on Arduino SE.